# Excel formula. Count ifs multiple conditions, but selective criteria (OR criteria)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the table:

[image]

On `column D` I need to count on first criteria: **Region**. It can be **South 1** or **Astana**, etc. And second criteria: If **column B** or **column C** have 1.

So rows must be counted if first criteria match. And second criteria: If column C or column B or both of them have 1 this row must be counted as 1.

---

I tried to use the formula **CountIfs**:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$443, $B$4, $C$1:$C$443, ">0", $D$1:$D$443, ">0")
```

---

But it counts only if all three criteria match.

> I need to match **first criteria** and **one of the remaining two or both of**
> **them**. How to implement that logic in formula?

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but there's a general math formula `Count(A OR B) = Count(A) + Count(B) - Count(A AND B)`. As `CountIfs()` is similar to the `AND` logical operator, maybe this is an idea?

Comment: Use and() with or() so and(Col A is 1,OR(Col B=1,Col C=1))

Comment: Can't you share a screenshot where it is obvious what needs to be done without too much explaining? IMO you're looking for a running count, Harun24hr thinks you're after a simple count and your incomplete screenshot could mean anything. Also, which is it: `>0` or `=1`?

Comment: Actually no difference =1 or >0 because anyway any number (1 or greater than 1) this row will count as 1. But not 0 or empty.

Comment: Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQDR0.jpg

Comment: Why your third row of data returns 0 on count if it meets first criteria where región = "south 1"? Is that green column your real expected output? Please clarify if region and brand criteria must be fulfilled **both** or just one of them

Comment: First I check if my rows have correct Region. For example South 1. Then I check remaining criteria. If column B or column C or both of them have values 1 or greater than 1 this row should be counted. If not it will not be counted even the first critiria Region match. Both.

Comment: So then region criteria **AND** brand criteria must be both fulfilled to return 1, right? Then, in that case, why your first row returns 1 on count if it does not match region properly?

Comment: You have completely made the query complicated however, from the thread what I have realized you need a formula like this and not `COUNTIF()` because you are looking per rows not by range: is that correct? Could you try this one then? `=((B2>0)+(C2>0))*(OR(A2={"South 1","Astana"}))`

Comment: Observe the mayhem you have caused. Here's what I think: `=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$443=A2)*(($B$2:$B$443>0)+($C$2:$C$443>0)>0))` following the 'loose' `AND(A,OR(B,C))` or `A*(B+C)` logics applying necessary corrections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple way to achieve this. One of them-

```
=ROWS(FILTER($A$2:$A$14,($A$2:$A$14=A2)*(($B$2:$B$14=1)+($C$2:$C$14=1))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

[image]

```
=IF(OR(A2="South 1";A2="Astana");IF(OR(B2=1;C2=1);1;0);0)
```

It will check first if region criteria is correct. In that case it will check then if `own brand` or `other brand` is 1. If true, return 1, else return 0.

So if the formula returns 0 could mean any of these options:

1. Region **is not** South 1
2. Region **is not** Astana
3. Neither own brand or Other brand is 1

Answer (score 1):

As commented above in thread. `COUNTIFS()` or not any fancy functions. Instead use the following as shown below in the screenshot.

[image]

---

```
=N(((B2>0)+(C2>0))*(OR(A2={"South 1","Astana"}))>0)
```

---

Or, Bit shorter version:

```
=N((OR(B2:C2>0))*(OR(A2={"South 1","Astana"}))>0)
```

---